# Why is dropdownlist options not getting updated?

Tags: jquery, function, api

In my UPDATE function I retrieve data from my database and its display in a table and in a dropdownlist (same data). The table(#table1) is getting updatet, but NOT the list (#stopcodes). Why?

function update() {

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/api/stop/',
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: "data",

    success: function (data) {

        $.each(data, function (i, data) {

            if (data.machinename == $("#selectmachine").val() && data.name != $(null).val() && data.overlimit == 1 && data.stopcause == $(null).val())
            {

                 var _id = data.id;
                 var _machinename = data.machinename;
                 var _stopcause = data.stopcause;
                 var _machinename = data.machinename;
                 var _name = data.name;
                 var _stop1 = data.idlestart;
                 var _stop2 = data.idlestop;
                 var _data = '<tr><td>' + _id + ' </td><td>' + _machinename + '</td><td>' + _name + '</td><td>' + _stop1 + '</td><td>' + _stop2 + '</td><td>';
                 var _data2 = '<option>' + _id + '</option>';
                 $('#table1').append(_data);
                 $('#stopcodes').append(_data2);

            };
        });
    }
});
```

[HTML CODE]

```
</head>
<body>
<div class ="w3-top">
<div class="w3-bar w3-black">
<span class="branding w3-bar-item w3-mobile">EVENTSOFT-MES System</span>
<span class="w3-right w3-mobile">
<a href="Home_page4.aspx" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-mobile" >HOME</a>
<a href="Login_page4.aspx" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-mobile">LOG PA MASKINE</a>
<a href="Stop_page4.aspx" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-mobile w3 w3-text-red “>STOP REGISTRERING</a>
</span>
</div></div>
<section class="showcase">
<div class="w3 container w3-center"></div>
<div style="background-color :#f2f2f2"></div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<h1>Company Brand</h1>
<h2>Company Slogan</h2>
<br />
<p id="displayTime"></p>
<br />
<br />
<select id="selectmachine" runat="server" width="200px"></select>
<br />
<br />
<select id="selectstopcode" runat="server" width="200px"></select>
<br />
<br />
<button id="update">Opdater</button>
<br />
<br />
<select id="stopcodes" runat="server" width="200px"></select>
<br />
<br />
<button id="stopreg">Registerer stoparsag</button>
<br />
<br />
<p id="notice"></p>
<br />
<br />
<table id="table1" >
<thead>
<tr>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you please share your HTML code?

Comment: Did you get my html?

Comment: Maybe something wrong at the client site please check this link. https://jsfiddle.net/wyjr5n34/

Comment: _id variable value shows correcly in the table but not in the list...

Comment: ` var _data =` <--- THat variable, your html is not valid